# Getting an Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to run this CRUD operations code using Hibernate. I am unable to fix the error.

I have tried with different Jars and looked for solutions online and failed to get rid of this error.

The following are the classes and configuration files that matter.

```
public class TrainDAO {

    Configuration c = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();

    public void insert(TrainDetails trainDetails)
    {
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(trainDetails);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void delete(int train_number)
    {
        s.beginTransaction();
        TrainDetails td = s.get(TrainDetails.class, train_number);
        s.delete(td);

        s.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public List<TrainDetails> fetch_by_train_number(int train_number)   {
        s.beginTransaction();
        List<TrainDetails> list = s.createQuery("from TrainDetails").list();

        s.getTransaction().commit();
        return list;
    }

    public List<TrainDetails> fetch_by_train_name(String train_name)    {
        s.beginTransaction();
        List<TrainDetails> list = s.createQuery("from TrainDetails").list();

        s.getTransaction().commit();
        return list;
    }

    public void update(int train_number, String train_type) {
        TrainDetails trainDetails = new TrainDetails();
        trainDetails.setTrain_number(train_number);
        trainDetails.setTrain_type(train_type);

        TrainDetails list = (TrainDetails) s.get(TrainDetails.class, train_number);
        s.update(trainDetails);

        s.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}

public class TrainDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrainDetails train = new TrainDetails();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = sc.nextInt();

        do {
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                train.setTrain_number(sc.nextInt());
                train.setTrain_name(sc.next());
                train.setOrigin(sc.next());
                train.setDestination(sc.next());
                train.setDistance(sc.nextInt());
                train.setFare(sc.nextInt());
                train.setTrain_type(sc.next());
                new TrainDAO().insert(train);
                break;
            case 2:
                int train_number = sc.nextInt();
                String train_name = sc.next();

                List<TrainDetails> list = new TrainDAO().fetch_by_train_number(train_number);
                List<TrainDetails> list1 = new TrainDAO().fetch_by_train_name(train_name);

                break;
            case 3:
                int train_number1 = sc.nextInt();
                String train_type = sc.next();

                new TrainDAO().update(train_number1, train_type);
                break;
            case 4:
                int train_number2 = sc.nextInt();

                new TrainDAO().delete(train_number2);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } while (true);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="simple.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Apart from this I have a POJO class and hbm.xml which points to the tables created in OracleSQL. When i run this code as Run As -> JAVA Application, i get a classLoaderDelegate error.

The following is the stacktrace of the error - 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.demo.dao.TrainDAO.<init>(TrainDAO.java:15)
    at com.demo.driver.TrainDriver.main(TrainDriver.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoaderDelegate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I have tried all the options and methods that I could find online. The basic difficulty is in understanding the error. I am unable to find `ClassLoaderDelegate` nor able to resolve this from the line numbers in my code.

Let me know where I have gone wrong.